# is there a function similar to matlab bwboundaries in opencv?

Tags: matlab, opencv, boundary

I need to find the boundaries of a binary image in opencv, but I can't find any picture to the matlab bwboundaries.
does it exist such a function?
thank you

Answer (score 3):

And If you don't want to try cvBlob since you will have to install another library.

Try cvContours() function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CvBlob](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/)  :)

I use it and it works great.